# Nested Flux Endpoint Calls

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I created an endpoint called `getApps`, that gets data from four different endpoints. `GetApps` takes the data from these four endpoints, transforms them into a unified `Apps` object then returns a list of these objects with Flux wrapped around it `Flux.just(List<Apps>)`. However, when calling `getApps` I'm not seeing any data being returned, only an empty list.

Here is my code in Kotlin. :

```
fun getApps(id: Long): Flux<Response> {
        val apps = mutableListOf<Apps>()
        var app1Success = SuccessEnum.NOT_QUERIED
        var app2Success = SuccessEnum.NOT_QUERIED
        var app3Success = SuccessEnum.NOT_QUERIED
        var app4Success = SuccessEnum.NOT_QUERIED


        //These call other endpoints using webclient.get(), which return Flux responses.
        val app1Response: Flux<app1Response> = fetchApps1Response(id)
        val app2Response: Flux<app2Response> = fetchApps2Response(id)
        val app3Response: Flux<app3Response> = fetchApps3Response(id)
        val app4Response: Flux<app4Response> = fetchApps4Response(id)

        val app1List = app1Response.collectList()
        val app2List = app2Response.collectList()
        val app3List = app3Response.collectList()
        val app4List = app4Response.collectList()

        app1List.subscribe { app1Res ->
            val app1SuccessAndAppList = processApps(app1Res, id)
            app1Success = app1SuccessAndAppList._1
            apps.addAll(app1SuccessAndAppList._2)
        }

        app2List.subscribe { app2Res ->
            val app2SuccessAndAppList = processApps(app2Res, id)
            app2Success = app2SuccessAndAppList._1
            apps.addAll(app2SuccessAndAppList._2)
        }

        app3List.subscribe { app3Res ->
            val app3SuccessAndAppList = processApps(app3Res, id)
            app3Success = app3SuccessAndAppList._1
            apps.addAll(app3SuccessAndAppList._2)
        }

        app4List.subscribe { app4Res ->
            val app4SuccessAndAppList = processApps(app4Res, id)
            app4Success = app4SuccessAndAppList._1
            apps.addAll(app4SuccessAndAppList._2)
        }
        
        return Flux.just(Response(
            app1Success = app1Success,
            app2Success = app2Success,
            app3Success = app3Success,
            app4Success = app4Success,
            apps = apps
        ))
    }
```

I'm also seeing that the SuccessEnum is being returned as SuccessEnum.NOT_QUERIED. This leads me to believe that I am just returning a Response object with the initialized values and not the data that is returned from the four other endpoints. Is it possible to return a flux object when I am waiting for the four other endpoints to return data? If so does anyone know where I went wrong? Thanks!

Note: I added a CountDownLatch and for each response I do a latch.countDown(). But this makes me wait for all the responses from the endpoints.

Comment: Do not use subscribe, and do not modify an external variable (apps).  Instead, `zip` you monos together.

Comment: You return `Flux.just` before the actual subscription receive anything. And, as mentioned above, don't use `subscribe` if you need the actual data.